# How do i import a project using node.js npm install on a package.json?

Tags: node.js, github, npm

I'm new to node.js and i have looked around about how to import a project from a package.json using node.js  with command:
 npm install "package name"

I have downloaded the project but i can't get it to work.

Where do i find the package name?

What should i type in order for it to work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Run the command `npm install` (without any arguments) in the directory where the package.json file is located. That will install ALL packages listed in package.json into a `node_modules` folder in the same directory.

---

Side note: When you start developing the project further and want to install new dependencies you can run `npm install somepackagename --save` and that will install the package into `node_modules` as well as adding a line into the package.json file, specifying which name and version of the package that was installed.

The idea is that you can upload a project folder, without `node_modules`, and anyone can download your project and just run `npm install` to download all dependencies.

Comment: I tried running 'npm install' on the cmd prompt and i get following error:

npm WARN saveError ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'c:\users\Alex\package.json'




npm WARN enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open  'c:\users\Alex\package.json'

npm  WARN Alex no description

npm  WARN Alex no repository field

npm  WARN no README data

npm  WARN No license field

When you said 'Run the command npm install (without any arguments) in the directory where the package.json file is located.'

How exactly does the cmd know where the package is located?

Comment: It's possible that something is weird with your npm installation. Which version of npm do you have installed? (Run `npm -v` to find out the version number) I did find a thread describing a similar error message https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/9161

Comment: "How exactly does the cmd know where the package is located?" The idea is that you can download a project folder, navigate to that folder, and run `npm install` - then npm will look for a `package.json` file and install everything listed in the `"dependencies"` field of that package.json file.

Comment: You could try installing an example repository just to see if that works. Here's a tiny node project as an example https://github.com/heroku/node-js-sample. To download it and install all dependencies you would do `cd C:\users\Alex`. Then run `git clone https://github.com/heroku/node-js-sample.git` to download the project into the folder `C:\users\Alex\node-js-sample`. 

Navigate to that folder using `cd node-js-sample` and then do `npm install` - whiich will create a `node_modules` folder and install all dependency packages listed in that package.json file. Try it and see.

Comment: Thanks, i finally got it to run by navigating correctly. I did not know i was supposed to use cd to get into the right directory.